# Memory leak in ABAddressBook iOS 8 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I am implementing `ABAddressBook` in iOS 8 and I started by creating a sample project to get going. I created the project using the Single View Application template. In the `viewDidAppear` of the `ViewController.swift` `ViewController` I added the code below:

```
if ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() != .Authorized {
    return
}
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
if let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) { granted, error in
        if error == nil && granted {
            if let contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
                for contact in contacts {
                    print("new contact")
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    print(error?.takeRetainedValue())
}
```

This is the only code I have and the app is leaking! I am running the Leaks tool and it does not give good enough context on why the app is leaking.

Leak Tool Snapshot
[image: Memory leaks tool snapshot]

Call Tree Snapshot

[image: Memory leak call tree snapshot]

Leak cycle Snapshot

[image: Memory leak cycle snapshot]

Am I not releasing something that should be? Also I can not call `CFRelease` because I have ARC enabled.

Comment: This code looks good to me. If you accidentally used `takeUnretainedValue` somewhere, that could leak, but I don't see that anywhere in your code snippet. iOS does have a few of these tiny leaks scattered about, so I wouldn't worry about them unless it's large or you see any of your classes not get deallocated. By the way, if possible, consider using the Contacts framework, which is easier to use and doesn't require the fragile process of `takeRetainedValue` calls that the AddressBook framework does.

Comment: `ABAddressBook` is deprecated in iOS 9. You'll probably benefit by moving to using `CNContactStore`.

Comment: @gjeck I am supporting iOS 8 devices so I can not use CNContactStore on iOS 8 devices.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce but for what it's worth the following produced no leaks either:

```
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?

func extractABAddressBookRef(abRef: Unmanaged<ABAddressBookRef>!) -> ABAddressBookRef? {
    if let ab = abRef {
        return Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(ab.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    return nil
}

func fetchAllContacts(completion: ((contacts: [String]?) -> Void)?) {
    let authorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .NotDetermined:
        print("requesting access...")
        var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        addressBook = extractABAddressBookRef(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &errorRef))
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, { [weak self] success, error in
            if success {
                completion?(contacts: self?.getContactNames())
            }
            else {
                print("error")
                completion?(contacts: nil)
            }
        })
    case .Denied, .Restricted:
        print("access denied")
        completion?(contacts: nil)
    case .Authorized:
        print("access granted")
        completion?(contacts: self.getContactNames())
    }
}

func getContactNames() -> [String]? {
    var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    addressBook = extractABAddressBookRef(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &errorRef))
    let contactList: NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()
    print("records in the array \(contactList.count)")

    return contactList.map({ (record: AnyObject) -> String in
        let contactRef: ABRecordRef = record
        let contactName: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactRef).takeRetainedValue() as String
        return contactName
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchAllContacts { (contacts) in
        print("fetched contacts \(contacts)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `takeRetainedValue`, not `takeUnretainedValue`, when getting the `AddressBookRef`. You also don't need to do the `fromOpaque`/`toOpaque` dance. (We had to do that in early Swift betas, but not anymore.)